# Highchart, Is there any other way to do this? In async drill down it is possible to drill from single series to mulitple

Tags: highcharts

Is there any other way to do this? In async drill down it is possible to drill from single series to mulitple.
 besides this method [`Link`](http://jsfiddle.net/49q18Lp3/) Because I use mysql I don't know how to configure +2 like this. 
 `series = [drilldowns[e.point.name], drilldowns[e.point.name + '2']];`

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what is the issue that you face? It seems that everything works as expected in the demo that you have shared.

Comment: I'm stuck with the problem that I use. mysql loops data but From looking at this code, there is a problem where series = [drilldowns[e.point.name], drilldowns[e.point.name + '2']]; when I loop I can't configure +2 like this in code.  series = [drilldowns[e.point.name], drilldowns[e.point.name + '2']];

Comment: It's okay. I solved the problem.